# Add column to another table and return as a List C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, list, return

I have the tabels: **main_data** and **user_data**

The table **main_data** has a foreign key **user_id** for the table **user_data**

I want to return a list, which contains all columns form the **main_data** table and the column **full_name** from the table **user_data**.

I already tried to do so, but unfortunately my code doesn't work.

```
public override IList<main_data> GetAllDetached()
{
    return this.context.main_data.Join(this.context.user_data, 
    o => o.user_id, i => i.user_data_id, (ud, fullName) => new {
    ud.user_id, fullName.full_name }).ToList();
}
```

The following error occurs:

> Cannot imlicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
>   **anonymous type: decimal user_id, string full_name**' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList **ProjectName.Model.main_data**'. An
>   explicit convirsion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: What is the definition of `it doesn't work?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a DTO Class  which is containing those properties from both the tables which are to be returned into the result:

```
 Class FinalResult
{
 public int user_id {get; set;}
 public string full_name {get; set;}
 }
```

Then in you code:

```
 public override List<FinalResult> GetAllDetached()
{

    var result = this.context.main_data.Join(this.context.user_data, 
    o => o.user_id, i => i.user_data_id, (ud, fullName) => new {
    ud.user_id, fullName.full_name }).ToList();

 var finalResult = result.Select(x => new FinalResult()
        {
            user_id = x.user_id ,
            full_name = x.full_name 

        }).ToList();
        return finalResult ;
}
```